# limit in group by in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I had a question about mysql.
Suppose I have a table as follows.
[database img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whovv.png)

In this table, I have 3 parameters: user, video and favorite_speed.

Now the question is, I want to get the average speed of the last 3 videos seen by each user in each course.
To connect the video to the course, we must have 2 joins between the course and the topic and the video.

For example, with the following code, I get the average speed of each user in a course. But the question is how do I get the average of the last 3 videos?

```
SELECT avg(favorite_speed),favorite_speed.user_id,topics.course_id 
FROM favorite_speed,videos,topics 
WHERE favorite_speed.video_id=videos.id AND topics.id=videos.topic_id 
GROUP BY user_id,videos.topic_id  
ORDER BY `avg(favorite_speed)`  DESC
```

Comment: By the way: the old join syntax was deprecated almost 30 years ago.

Comment: MySQL 5.x or MySQL 8?  Please also include example data, as per the following advice...  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: It might be easier for you to just dump a picture of the data, but if you took a little while to add the data in a usable form like a table dump or an SQLFiddle, then someone here could recreate the data and test an answer, which **in the long run** would benefit your

Comment: How do you define the last three?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now the question is, I want to get the average speed of the last 3 videos seen by each user in each course.

You can use a window function to identify the most recent three videos.  Assuming it is based on `favorite_speed.id`:

```
SELECT fs.user_id, v.course_id, avg(fs.favorite_speed), 
FROM (SELECT fs.user_id, fs.favorite_speed, v.course_id,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITON BY fs.user_id, v.course_id ORDER BY fs.id DESC) as seqnum
      FROM favorite_speed fs JOIN
           videos v 
           ON fs.video_id = v.id 
     ) fsv
WHERE seqnum <= 3
GROUP BY fs.user_id, v.course_id; 
ORDER BY avg(fs.favorite_speed) DESC;
```

Note that the `topics` table is not needed because the information is in the `videos` table.

Comment: i think ROW_NUMBER function work in my sql 8 but my sql version is 5.5